# Find $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^{+} }\left(\frac{82\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}\right)$ without L'hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is exist the way to calculate:

$$
\lim_{x \to 1^{+} }\frac{82sin(\pi x)}{1-x}
$$

Without using the L'hopital rule. From L'hopital rule i got $82\pi$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Hint:** Use the substitution $x\leadsto x-1$, then use the addition formula for $\sin$.

Comment: Think about the derivative of $x\mapsto \sin(\pi x)$ at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

as $\sin(\pi) = 0$ the limit is the derivative of $x\to \sin(\pi x)$ in $x=1$:
$$
-82 \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin (\pi x) - \sin(\pi)}{x - 1} = -82\pi\cos(\pi) = 82\pi
$$

Comment: I use the definition of the derivative. without it, how do you define the function $\sin$?

Comment: You are right!:)

Comment: A very nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve the limit by a couple of substitutions. Letting $y=1-x$ we have $$\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{82\sin(\pi-\pi y)}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{82(\sin\pi\cos(\pi y)-\sin(\pi y)\cos\pi)}{y}=\\ \lim_{y\to0^-} \frac{-82\sin(\pi y)}{y}=82\cdot\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(\pi y)}{y}.$$
Let $z=\pi y$ to finally obtain $$82\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{\sin z}{z/\pi}=82\pi\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{\sin z}{z}=82\pi. $$

Comment: @bimbabi You're welcome! If you're satisfied with the answers, consider accepting one.